# Can I insert a HTML file containing scripts and styles into another HTML (on client side)?

Tags: javascript, html, arduino

Can I insert a HTML file containing scripts and styles into another HTML (on client side)?

I will try to elaborate a bit so it's clear what I wish to do... First of all, this will be served by an Arduino, so the whole point of this is to minimize the number of data sent on each request, and if possible have only two files (one small file that needs to be loaded on every request, and one big file which should be loaded only the first time, then be cached by the browser).

Currently I have something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            Many lines of CSS...
        </style>
        <script>
            Many lines of Javascript
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Many lines of HTML
    </body>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready
        (
            function()
            {
                initializeStuff("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9");
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Basically, I have this big page, but the only thing that may change on each GET request is the data on the `initializeStuff()` function. Tin functions then updates many parts of the body with this new data.

I know the normal thing would be to have different files for [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets), [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) and HTML content, but if it's possible I would like to have everything in one big file. I wanted this because the Arduino is very limited in terms of connections, so if a browser starts to send many GETs in parallel most of them will fail.

So my question if there is a way to have most of the data in one big file that can be cached by the browser, so that after this file is in the cache I only need to load a really small and basic HTML file, with little more than the `initializeStuff()` function (and whatever else is required do reference all the other stuff in the big file)?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It's important to restate your question in your body (if it is in your title).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will meet your requirement, but for JavaScript, you can link with external files like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

And for external stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
```

Comment: Yes i know i can link several different files with different content on separate files, but i wanted to know if there was a way to have tham all in a single big file?